# Component prop not changing when select value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got the following code for a SchoolsList component:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import ClassesList from "../classes/ClassesList"

const SchoolsList = () => {
    const schools = useSelector(selectAllSchools)
    if (schools.length === 0) {
        return <h2>No schools created yet</h2>
    }

    let selectedSchool = schools[0]
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        selectedSchool = schools[e.target.value]
        document.getElementById("schoolName").innerText = "Name: " + selectedSchool.name
    }

    return (
        <div className='SchoolsList'>
            <select onChange={handleChange}>
                {schools.map((school, id) => <option key={id} value={id}>{school.name}</option>)}
            </select>
            <h3>Selected school</h3>
            <h4 id="schoolName">Name: {selectedSchool.name}</h4>
            <ClassesList classes={selectedSchool.classes} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default SchoolsList
```

When the value of the select changes, and the variable selectedSchool changes, the ClassesList component prop isn't updated.  I'm pretty new to react-reduce so I'm a bit lost as to what to do. How can I update the value of the prop when the select changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is there is no re-rendering happening. Try using the useState or useRef hook to store the value of the selected school.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
    selectedSchool:''
})
```

Then save the value of the selected school within state. Use an useEffect to set state with the initial value of school of your choice.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    setState({...state, selectedSchool:schools[0]})
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it your way and it worked like a charm.  I tried doing it creating a selectedSchool slice and using selectors, but I can't use selectors inside callback functions or inside the return.  Do you know if there's a way around that?

Comment: If by selectors you mean the useSelector hook , the useSelector is only used to get values from the redux state. Once you get the value and store it in a variable , you can do anything with it using normal typescript or javascript functions for example looping through it if its an array, after all actions then you can update the redux state using useDispatch. But i highly advice  you to use useState for state that not global

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `selectedSchool` is not reactive, you can use hook `useState` and it will be update state in props. Example:

```
    const [setSelectedSchool, selectedSchool] = useState(schools[0]);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
          setSelectedSchool(schools[e.target.value])
    }
```

Also you don't need to do this `document.getElementById("schoolName").innerText = "Name: " + selectedSchool.name` it's incorrect.

You have correct JSX `<h4 id="schoolName">Name: {selectedSchool.name}</h4>` already